# Cat redirection auto kill?

Tags: linux, unix, signals, cat

I'm trying to do the following :

```
cat > somefile "some text" <ctrl+d>; clear; some other program
```

but without having to press 
   <"ctrl + d"> 
so that line will create the file and then run some other program. I tried echo "some text" > somefile; but there are too many special chars for that. Anyone know a way around this

Comment: Your question is unclear; would a here document satisfy your requirement, or do you actually require input to come from the user? Then how do you know when the user is done? However, if a single line of input is required, the `read` command does that. In some versions of the shell, it also has a timeout facility.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you may be looking for is something along these lines:

```
pax> cat >tempfile ; tput clear ; someprog
Enter your data here for tempfile
<ctrl-d>
**screen clears and someprog runs**
```

The end-file <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> isn't part of the *command* you enter, it's part of the input stream for the `cat` command.

If you don't want to use the input stream, you're either going to have to work out the `echo` variant (learn to embrace the wonderful world of shell escapes - you can get around *most* of them by just using single quotes instead of double ones), or simply create your input file in advance and use something like:

```
cp sourcefile tempfile ; tput clear ; someprog
```

Comment: Edited I'm trying to do it so you don't have to press ctrl+d it auto exits on a ; or something.

Comment: @Morki, I'm not sure how _any_ character is better than CTRL-D since you have to enter extra characters regardless. See the second bit of my answer to do this with no extra user input (other than the creation of `sourcefile` once).

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to write some text in `somefile` in multiple lines or with special characters, you should try this. EOF is treated as a special string here that will terminate `cat` automatically when found but it could be anything else.

```
cat > somefile << EOF
some text
EOF

some other program
```

Comment: Actually `EOF` isn't special at all; you can put anything you like after `<<` and the first occurrence of that string alone on a line will terminate the so-called here document. This is a shell facility, not a feature of `cat`.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've said it ambiguously, you're absolutely right. => edited.

Comment: You can do something like cat > somefile << EOF
some text
EOF;
someprog;

Comment: It's commonly referred to as [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).